# memory allocation error while converting string to char*

Tags: c++, memory

I need some help figuring out a memory allocation error. I keep getting this error:

> Error: Memory could not be allocated.

...when `fList` is large in the following code:

```
for (unsigned int ii=0; ii<fList.size(); ii++) {

    char *fName = new char[fList[ii].length() + 1];
    strcpy(fName, fList[ii].c_str());
    err = xInitFile(fName, ii+1);
    if(err != 0) {
        cout << "FOOBAR" << endl;
    }               
    delete[] fName;
}
```

`fList` is a `std::vector<std::string>`.

The function `xInitFile` is a C shared library function with the following prototype:

```
int xInitFile(char *fName, int fHandle)
```

If `fList` is small, then everything runs fine. I'm pretty sure the problem lies in how I'm converting the string to a `char *`, but I can't figure out how to fix it. As far as I can tell, `fName` is always deleted, so it doesn't appear to be a memory leak. My memory usage doesn't spike while running the code either.

EDIT:

Commenting out `err = xInitFile(fName, ii+1);` eliminates the error.  That means the allocation error is occurring in the `xInitFile`, right?  I didn't think to try this earlier, because I thought the problem was in my code (b/c I'm new to C++).

Comment: So who prints 'Error: Memory could not be allocated.'? Is it even related to your memory allocation? It seems like you are showing unrelated piece of code here...

Comment: is it not better if you delete fName inside of the for loop?that way you use it and discard it immediately. may be since your not deleting and in every iteration your are getting a new location for fName leading to memorycongestion

Comment: wrap the line with `new` with try/catch and print in catch something. If you'll see your message, then this error is generated by `new`, in other case - by `xInitFile`

Comment: Agree with the length print.  My guess is you might be receiving a negative number or something.

Comment: Or just comment-out the xInitFile call and simulate chewing on the string. And while you're at it, there is no reason to use `new char[]` in this in the first place. If you must have a raw, writable buffer that acts like a c-string, then use `std::vector<char>`, `resize()` it to your string `length()+1`, `std::copy()` the elements, and pass the vector-base-address. Or use a back inserter and push a 0 at the end. Either way, let the scope fallout throw it away for you.

Comment: @nos - Lengths are all positive ints ~60.  If I try `xInitFile(fList[ii].c_str(), ii+1);`, I get cannot convert `const char *` to `char *`
@VladLazarenko - It is output to the console.  It occurs after the `char *fName = new char[fList[ii].length() + 1];` line.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably frowned upon for one reason or another, but I'd be inclined to instead try `strdup`.

```
char *fName = strdup( fList[ii].c_str() );
```

paired with

```
free(fName);
```

Comment: The only downside of `strdup` is that it isn't (C or C++) standard.  It's Posix, and you'll get a warning about it with VC++ (where you can use `_strdup` instead).  It's quite simple to write your own, but in fact, I'd use something which extracted a C++ string into an `std::vector<char>`, and use that.  Or create a class which did just that: it's only a couple of lines of code, and if you're frequently interfacing to legacy C which _outputs_ to a `char*`, it's worth the effort.  (If the legacy C doesn't output, just using `std::string::c_str()` is sufficient.)